# Using a variable in another class?

Tags: php, oop

I have this on my class file

```
class Bet {    
  private $Client;
  private $Secret;
  private $Server;  
  private $result;  
  private $Result;
  public function Bet($Type, $Chance) {    
      $this->Client = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
      $this->Secret = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
      $this->Server = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

      if($Type == 'auto') {    
              $hash  = hash('sha512', $this->Client . $this->Secret . $this->Server);
              $Result = round(hexdec(substr($hash, 0, 8)) / 42949672.95, 2);

                  if($Result < $Chance) {
                      $this->result = true;
                      return $Result;
                  } else {
                      $this->result = false; 
                     return $Result;                     
                  }      
      }

  }
  /**
  * @return boolean
  */

  public function isReturnLessThanChance() { return $this->result; }
  public function returnLucky() { return "4"; }  }
```

On my other file I'm doing

```
$bet = new Bet('auto', $chance);
$lucky = $bet->returnLucky();
```

I am able to get the number 4 (testing) but I can't seem to return $result

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the construct method, you should do `$this->Result = $Result;` instead of  `return $Result;`,

then use `return $this->Result;` in `returnLucky()`.

And you should avoid use variable like `$result` and `$Result`, which is confusing.

Comment: I got it to work with your advice, what is the "contruct method", the if result < chance statements? I got it working putting it in the if statement.

Comment: @user3026745 The method with same name of the class `Bet` is the construt method. If you are using php 5, use `__construct` is better.

Comment: I tried putting the construct in the bet class and function but I kept getting undefined variable error. Should I be calling it a different way?

Comment: @user3026745 you got two result variable 1 ucfirst and 1 lcfirt can you remove the 1 ucfirst coz i see in your class that you are not using it.